# Way to stop deploy wrong kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

We have a set of kubernetes yamls which is management by `kustomize` and they will be deployed to different clusters. Each cluster is slightly different which means every environment will have a sub directory (`environ/<envname>`) including some special kustomization overwrite.

We will manually deploy new version to different environments by command `kubeclt apply -k environ/env`. But sometimes we do stupid thing like this: `kubectl apply -k environ/env1` to the cluster `env2` . So is there some method to stop doing a `kubectl apply` to a wrong environment?

Comment: If you were `kubectl`, how would you know it's the wrong environment?

Comment: So I think it may be some bash alias to prevent the wrong deploy? Bash can get the current kubectl content.

Comment: I'd use shell scripts and different configs for each cluster, like that: `deploy-cluster1.sh` where I'd have `kubectl --kubeconfig .kube/cluster1 apply -k environ/cluster1` or even shorter: `deploy.sh env1` where `deploy.sh` contains: `kubectl --kubeconfig .kube/$1 apply -k environ/$1`  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

Comment: @VASャ Yeah, that is a good method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

If you are aware that you made a mistake and want to cancel the command right away than there are some options for you:

- `$ kill -9 $!` will kill the most recent process executed by the command (`$!` represents its process ID).
- Suspend the current process by pressing `Ctrl+z` and then kill it using `kill -9 %%` or `kill -9 %+`. More details regarding this approach can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html#SEC33).

**EDIT:**

Including the solution proposed by VASャ from the comments:

> I'd use shell scripts and different configs for each cluster, like
> that: `deploy-cluster1.sh` where I'd have `kubectl --kubeconfig .kube/cluster1 apply -k environ/cluster1` or even shorter: `deploy.sh env1` where `deploy.sh` contains: `kubectl --kubeconfig .kube/$1 apply -k environ/$1`

More details regarding that approach can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/).

Comment: No, after `k apply` it is too late to `kill`. So I think the key point is to valid before the real `apply`.

Comment: I see. In that case, would the solution proposed by VASャbe better for you?

Comment: That is great. And the reference link is also quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got a new solution here.

[direnv](https://direnv.net/) which can change env after switch into different directories this force me to switch the `KUBECONFIG` env. Follow [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75) to get more details.